# What does the fading selection color mean?

Tags: vertices

In the picture you can see that the last vertex selected on the edge loop is somewhat separated by a color change from the rest of the selection. What does this mean?

[image]

Comment: The fade from orange to black along an edge means that the edge in question is connected to the selected vertex, even if the edge itself is not selected. The situation in your screenshot is caused by two vertices in the same place. These are called *doubles* and can be automatically merged via `W` *> Specials > Remove Doubles*.

Comment: Somewhere there was an option to adjust this fade. In themes? Or somewhere else?

Comment: Hi, @blenduser, it would be in Themes > 3D View.. but I haven't been able to find a setting that alters the fade. The colour is set by 'Edge Select'. SE sites have a structure: a question followed by ranked answers, no.. supplementary questions can't be asked in the answer section. If your question is sufficiently distinct, ask it in its own right. You could chase this one down.. but personally,  I don't believe you can adjust this aspect of the display.. sorry..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually two vertices in the exact same position there, which can be seen as you noted by the differences in edge shading.

I would box select where the manipulator (the blue, green, red arrows) are and either hit alt-m to merge  or hit <kbd>W</kbd> > Remove doubles.

Comment: ah too slow, gandalf3 beat me to it.